# 4 Column Adaptive issue

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a 4 column layout. id="col4"
each column is set to 25% width displayed inline-block and floated left.

If i were to leave it as it, it becomes responsive quite nicely. However, i have a media query that once the width reaches below max-width: 700px. I want a 2 column layout. So i do this by simply increasing #col4's width from 25% to 50%, this naturally forces the 2 columns to the right to drop below the first two columns.

```
#col4 {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
}
```

into

```
@media only screen and (max-width:700px)
{
   #col4 {
     display: inline-block;
     float: left;
     width: 50%;
   }

   .c3, {
     clear: right;
   }
}
```

If all 4 columns would be the same height, there would be no issue. However in my case any of the 4 columns can be an unpredictable height and when the 4 column wide layout turns into 2x2 wide layout the columns stagger oddly.

I figured that i would have to clear:left on .c3 and possibly .c4 however other issues arise.

If i clear:left on both .c3 and .c4... the 2 columns will stack on top o each other creating a layout of 2x1x1 instead of 2x2.

Also, if i only clear:left on .c3 they mostly stagger correctly, except that c3 cannot clear:right for c4.

This is the outcome. http://jsfiddle.net/hfG98/

Any idea, how i could get .c3 and .c4 to alight themselves directly under .c1 and .c2 ?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

CSS syntax is really silly sometimes. Look at this little tiny comma right after the .c3

```
.c3, {
```

i think you lost some times because of this ;)

---

Another thing: Why don't you use something like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for your project. Here is a [list](https://delicious.com/desandro/likemasonrybutnot) of masonry like plugins. Masonry is really a great plugin and free to use.

Comment: I actually started using masonry, however it really did not like loading nicely on an iPhone.